# Failed to process import candidates for configuration class error is comming

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I shared pom file i'm getting this error "Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.data.insert.SimpleRestApisApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.audit.AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration" can anyone try to give solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
            <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
                <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
            </parent>
            <groupId>com.data.insert</groupId>
            <artifactId>DataInsertSupportTool</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <name>DataInsertSupportTool</name>
            <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

            <properties>
                <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            </properties>

        <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

                <dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>

        </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

        <dependency>

        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>

        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>

        <version>3.12</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Alpha2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>

        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>

        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>

        <version>3.1.0</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

        </project>
```

Comment: i have tried maven clean and install still same error im getting

Comment: I don't think the mentioned exception has much to do with the pom.xml file. What did you do exactly, when you got the exception?

Comment: I deleted project and again imported then I done maven clean and maven install after that also same error

Comment: If you are working with Spring Boot...there is already a definition for hibernate-core defined in spring boot. Also remove the json dependency cause Spring boot uses jackson. That means don't try to use different version manually (except you know 100% what you are doing). Furthermore if you need more up-to-date than upgrade to most recent version of spring boot (2.3.1.RELEASE)...Apart from all previous if you have an error you should post that error here and of course your code